# Simplest way to validate an input against a file of words?

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to validate a `gets` input against a very long word list (a list of all the English words available)?

I am currently playing with `readlines` to manipulate the text, but before there's any manipulation, I would like to first validate the entry against the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way, but by no means the fastest, is to simply search against the word list each time.  If the word list is in an array:

```
if word_list.index word
    #manipulate word
end
```

If, however, you had the word list as a separate file (with each word on a separate line), then we'll use [`File#foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002268) to find it:

```
if File.foreach("word.list") {|x| break x if x.chomp == word}
   #manipulate word
end
```

Note that `foreach` does not strip off the trailing newline character(s), so we get rid of them with [`String#chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000751).

Comment: This did the trick... i was able to wrap my program and create a error message if the word isn't matched.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example using a `Set`, though Mark Johnson is right,
a bloom filter would be more efficient.

```
require 'set'

WORD_RE = /\w+/

# Read in the default dictionary (from /usr/share/dict/words),
# and put all the words into a set
WORDS = Set.new(File.read('/usr/share/dict/words').scan(WORD_RE))

# read the input line by line
STDIN.each_line do |line|
  # find all the words in the line that aren't contained in our dictionary
  unrecognized = line.scan(WORD_RE).find_all { |term| not WORDS.include? term }

  # if none were found, the line is valid
  if unrecognized.empty?
    puts "line is valid"
  else # otherwise, the line contains some words not in our dictionary
    puts "line is invalid, could not recognize #{unrecognized.inspect}"
  end
end
```

Comment: you obviously have much more experience than me :) i will study this

Answer (score 0):

are you reading the list from a file?
can't you have it all in memory?
maybe a [finger tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree) may help you
if not, there's not more than "read a chunk of data from the file and grep into"

Answer (score 0):

Read the word list into memory, and for each word, make an entry into a hash table:

```
def init_word_tester
    @words = {}

    File.foreach("word.list") {|word| 
        @words[word.chomp] = 1
    }
end
```

now you can just check every word against your hash:

```
def test_word word
    return @words[word]
end
```